# Domain Exclusion Data Extension, How to Use it?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a domain exclusion DE with single field "Domain" and entered values for the field as "gmail.com".

Now how do I add this data extension to email under "User Initiated Email". I already tried selecting DE in Excluded DE but it didn't work. I already tried using domain value as "@gmail.com" but still it didn't work.

Can you please help me how to utilize this DE?

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to use the out of the box method of using a data extension created with the Domain Exclusion Data Extension Template, and (surprise, surprise) it's throwing an unspecified error when I try to send the email.

For no particular reason, I suspect the cause is that I'm trying to use the Domain Exclusion functionality in conjunction with other exclusion scripts. So, I'm going to try using a regular exclusion expression that performs a lookup against the Domain Exclusion Data Extension.

And since I didn't find this anywhere else on StackExchange... and I'd already written it... thought I might as well share. Here's what I wrote:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("ENT.DomainExclusion_Master","Domain", Domain(emailaddr)))>0
```

(If it works for you, appreciate an up-vote. I'm a noob, and can use the points.)

Answer (score 1):

I know that Trigger Send Definitions (and Journey Builder Sends) have a section for utilizing this DE (Right next to the Exclusion Script area).

I am not sure yet if the Guided Send or User Initiated Sends currently have this as a setting. I believe that UI sends were announced to have this as a capability, but I do not know this is available for sure.

Your best bet is to contact your SFMC Rep and ask them about using it outside of just on Triggers. They will likely have the full information on where this DE is applicable and where you might need to use [exclusion scripts still](https://sprignaturemoves.com/exclude-an-email-domain-from-a-send/)

Comment: Thanks... I already have experienced with script based. I was just learning and testing DE based exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Domain Exclusions do work with UI Sends. You need to create the Data Extension with a DomainExclusion Template. Once this is created, the option will show in the Audience section of your Send Definition.

Populate your data extension with the domains you want excluded e.g. google.com

Comment: I have created DE from DmainExclusion template. But in UI sends, I don't see any option for selecting DomainExlusion DE? Its only showing targeted and excluded DEs. Under Exclude option I added exclusion DE but it did't work.

Answer (score 1):

The area will appear under Advanced Exclusion (just below the excluded and suppressed box).
Click on Advanced Exclusion and you will see Domain Exclusion.

In order to work you need to create a new DE from a template and select the domain exclusion.

[image]

[image]

Drag the data extension in the box and proceed with the send

Comment: In addition, please note you need to click Select button to find the DomainExclusion data extension. 

DomainExclusion only works with data extensions, if you are using salesforce campaigns/reports doesn't work.